# Python import error -works in interpreter

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lin.py", line 9, in <module>
    from linkedin import linkedin
  File "/home/cloudera/python/linkedin.py", line 9, in <module>
    from linkedin import linkedin
ImportError: cannot import name linkedin
```

Don't know what's the problem. Its working fine in the interpreter.

Any clues?

Answer (score 6):

You named one of your files `linkedin.py`, hiding the module you actually want to import. Name it something else.