# Importing Python module works in interpreter but not script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I pip-installed the module `absl`, and I'm able to successfully import it in the interpreter, but when I run a script that imports it, I get the error `ImportError: No module named absl`. What gives?

I know [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989986/python-import-error-works-in-interpreter) reports the same error, but since this isn't in regards to a package I created (it's part of [Google's Python certificate-transparency tools](https://github.com/google/certificate-transparency/tree/master/python)), I don't believe the problem concerns shadowing a filename.

Answer (score 3):

Verify what python interpreter is running your script

```
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

Also verify if for whatever reason your python interpreter is runing from a virtualenv

```
import sys

if hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix'):
```

Make sure the interpreter | venv that is running your script; is the one the absl package was installed for

Answer (score 1):

I was using someone else's script, whose shebang was `#!/usr/bin/env python`. However, my default `python` version was 2.7, whereas I had downloaded the absl module for python3 via pip3. Once I changed the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, Python was able to find the absl module.

Comment: *`#!/usr/bin/env python` … changed the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env python`* Hmm?

Comment: @phd Omg, that's what I get for recklessly cutting and pasting. Fixed. Thank you!